# Show elements from side of page with jquery as scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want a jquery plugin But i don't know what its name!

Check this page : http://www.adro.ir/

As you scroll on the page, the elements get appears from one side of the screen.

How can i do it with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrooldeck.js

Info found here:
http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/

Answer (score 1):

All these jquery plugin are used in this site

bxSlider

Response jQuery Content Slider
jQuery Masonry

Masonry is a layout plugin for jQuery. Think of it as the flip side of CSS floats.

GSAP

GSAP is a suite of tools for scripted, high-performance HTML5 animations that work in all major browsers from GreenSock.

Modernizr

Modernizr allows you to target specific browser functionality in your stylesheet.

Modernizr 2.6

jQuery Waypoints

Waypoints is a small jQuery plugin that makes it easy to execute a function whenever you scroll to an element.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks but which one it that i need ?!

Comment: i think bxSlider for content slider